# Lighttpd error sockets disabled, out-of-fds

Tags: fastcgi, centos6, lighttpd

I have used lighttpd for a long, since its very fast for busy webapplications ins fast-cgi(PHP)

2 or 3 months ago sometimes I got this erro:

```
2015-07-06 17:58:55: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:58:55: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:58:59: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:58:59: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:05: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:05: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:10: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:10: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:14: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:14: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:18: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:18: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:22: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:22: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
2015-07-06 17:59:26: (server.c.1398) [note] sockets enabled again
2015-07-06 17:59:26: (server.c.1446) [note] sockets disabled, out-of-fds
```

I was using version  1.4.29 and now after upgrade to  1.4.35 the problem persists. Since then I've been looking very different solutions and found nothing that could help me.

Some relevant config info:

h2. lighttpd.conf

```
server.username  = "lighttpd"
server.groupname = "lighttpd"
server.event-handler = "linux-sysepoll"
server.max-fds = 4096 #same as ulimit -n
server.max-connections = 2048
server.stat-cache-engine = "simple"
server.max-keep-alive-idle = 5
server.max-keep-alive-requests = 4
server.max-read-idle = 30
server.max-write-idle = 360
```

h2. fast-cgi.conf

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )

fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
                   ( "php-local" =>
                     (
                       "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi-1.socket",
#                      "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi-1.socket"+var.PID,
                       "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                       "max-procs" => 30,
                       "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                     )
                   ),
                   ( "php-tcp" =>
                     (
                       "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                       "port" => 9999,
                       "check-local" => "disable",
                       "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                     )
                   ),
                   ( "php-tcp2" =>
                     (
                       "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                       "port" => 9998,
                       "check-local" => "disable",
                       "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                     )
                   ),

                   ( "php-num-procs" =>
                     (
                       "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi-2.socket",
                       "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                       "max-procs" => 30,
                       "bin-environment" => (
                         "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "30",
                         "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "2048",
                       ),

                       "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable",
                     )
                   ),
                )
```

This server is dedicated to that application.

Is running at more than four years with at least 2 lighttpd php applications with large volumes of access, the record was in 2013 with 14,000 unique visits and 85,000 page views, then this record had no problems with the limit.
Today keep the average 8,000 visitors and 44,000 page views per day.

:

[image: Visual info about the machine]

What's wrong?

Comment: Are there other services running on the machine that may have begun using file descriptors? Perhaps you have been hacked and don't know it?

Comment: I think not. Just this process, php-cgi, mysql, named(dns) newrelic and lighttpd... 
Could a php application thats uses fopen() cause that?

About being hacked, this problems happens with a ddos attack, but my system is up.

Comment: Any application that opens files or sockets could cause it. Look at `lsof` output. If that fails to show the reason, remember that rootkits will tamper with lsof but cannot hide their file descriptor usage against the ulimit.

Comment: Its list a lot of php-cgi files, almost 900 process. I think its normal for a busy http server.

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd 1.4 keeps an internal count of (some of the) file descriptors it has opened.  lighttpd 1.4 disables the server sockets when its internal count (cur_fds + want_fds -- line 1408 of src/server.c) reaches 90% of server.max-fds from lighttpd.conf

It is possible (unsubstantiated) that the internal count does not match the actual number of file descriptors in use.

If this happens again, would you check how many fds are actually used by the lighttpd server process?  If the lighttpd server process has pid 1234, then check the number of open fds of a process on Linux with

```
ls -1 /proc/1234/fd/ | wc -l
```

**If** the result is much less than 90% of server.max-fds (which you have set to 4096), then that would suggest a bug in lighttpd internal fd count.  You can go to http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/issues and Register for an account.  Then, you'll be able to submit a bug report.

Again, **if** this is the problem, you might also look at your application to see how frequently it is encountering fatal errors, dying, and being restarted.